# Why is hexane called skellysolve-B

Tags: organic-chemistry, solvents

https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/hexane
Another name for hexane is skellysolve-B, is that just to be silly?

Comment: Presumably that was/is a trade name.

Answer (score 4):

It's probably considerably notorious historical trade name. In many older publications, e.g. "Skellysolve B ([petroleum ether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petroleum_ether))"<sup>[1,2]</sup> appears for solvent used.

It was a product or trade name of [Skelly Oil Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skelly_Oil)<sup>[3]</sup>
 founded in 1919.

It's not a pure hexane, rather narrow-boiling hexane oil fraction.<sup>[3]</sup>

I could find analysis of similar product **Skellysolve C**, which is C7 heptane fraction:<sup>[3]</sup>

- 24.9% heptane
- 22.9%

  - 2,3-dimethylpentane
  - 2-methylhexane
  - 3-methylhexane
- 19.3%

  - *trans*-1,2-dimethylcyclopentane
  - *trans*-1,3-dimethylcyclopentane
- 15.0% methylcyclohexane
- 5.5% cyclohexane
- 5.2% heavy nonaromatics
- 2.7% toluene
- 2.5% hexane
- …

Other ones:<sup>[4]</sup>

> **Skellysolve A** is essentially *n*-pentane, b 28-30°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve B** is essentially *n*-hexane, b 60-68°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve C** is essentially *n*-heptane, b 90-100°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve D** is mixed heptanes, b 75-115°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve E** is mixed octanes, b 100-140°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve F** is petroleum ether, b 30-60°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve G** is petroleum ether, b 40-75°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve H** is hexanes and heptanes, b 69-96°/atm,
>   **Skellysolve L** is essentially octanes, b 95-127°/atm.

Unfortunately, Chemical Abstracts Service, mixes names for different substances, including this tradename: “*n*-hexane”, “hexane (all isomers)”, “Skellysolve B” under single CAS RN 110-54-3.<sup>[5]</sup>

---

References:

1. Newman, H.; Zilversmit, D. [Quantitative Aspects of Cholesterol Flux in Rabbit Atheromatous Lesions](http://www.jbc.org/content/237/7/2078.short). Journal of Biological Chemistry **1962**, *237* (7), 2078–2084.
2. Holick, M. F.; DeLUCA, H. F. [A New Chromatographic System for Vitamin D3, and Its Metabolites: Resolution of a New Vitamin D3, Metabolite](http://www.jlr.org/content/12/4/460.short). J. Lipid Res. **1971**, *12* (4), 460–465.
3. Griswold, J.; Andres, D.; Berg, C. F. V.; Kasch, J. E. [Pure Hydrocarbons from Petroleum - Separation of Straight-Run Fractions by Distex Process](https://doi.org/10.1021/ie50434a019). *Ind. Eng. Chem*. **1946**, *38* (1), 65–70.
4. Armarego, W. L. *Purification of Laboratory Chemicals*; Butterworth-Heinemann, **2017**.
5. [CommonChemistry.org – CAS Registry Number: 110-54-3](http://commonchemistry.org/ChemicalDetail.aspx?ref=110-54-3)